# Generally set onClickListener to inflated xml button

Tags: android, forms, onclick, android-custom-view

I have a custom edittext that acts like a form. It has a label, edit text and a button. I am using the tag  to include it in a layout so I can use the form repeatedly. The function I want the button to have is to reproduce the form when it is clicked. This is possible for me on the first click of the first form. However when I click the button of the new form there is no action. However if I click the first forms button a new form is created. This is my xml: that I include.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/form_textview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp" android:text="Number:" />
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/form_edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/form_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_example" android:paddingLeft="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is how I am trying to dynamically add new forms:

```
public final void onClick(final View view) 
{

    if (view == findViewById(R.id.form_button))
    {
        try{
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contacteditll);

                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View tempView = vi.inflate(R.layout.form, null);
                numberEntryViews.add(tempView);

                layout.addView(tempView);
                ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) tempView.findViewById(R.id.form_button);

                btn.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(TAG, "Failed to inflate");
            }
        }
}
```

I have tried various ways in implementing this but I am having no luck. Any help or suggestions would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this line will not be true if you click the newly created button

```
    if (view == findViewById(R.id.form_button))
```

you could assign a fixed id to the newly created button, or try working with offsets

Answer (score 0):

I figured I had to make a class level button and view to update the function of the button from the new form.

```
        try{
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contacteditll);
        LinearLayout layout2 = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.numbersll);

        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        tempView = vi.inflate(R.layout.form, null);
        numberEntryViews.add(tempView);

        layout2.addView(tempView);
        btn = (ImageButton) tempView.findViewById(R.id.form_button);
        //TODO: Work from here. Ask on Stack Overflow.
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to inflate");
    }
```

btn is class level and is updated on every click. Removes function from the last button which makes sense in my case.